# Covert date string and time string to time

Tags: php

I have 2 strings

```
$date1 = $_POST['date1']; // example: 22/07/2014
$time1 = $_POST['time1']; // example: 12:05
```

How i can compare if this input time has passed ?

I tried but its not working :

```
$date3 = $date1 . ' ' . $time1;
$date4 = strtotime($date3);

if(time()>$date4)...
```

Any help ? thanks.

Comment: Read this note in the `strtotime()` docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `strtotime` reads dates as mm/dd/yyyy. You need to change the input date to dd-mm-yyyy

```
$date1 = str_replace('/','-', $date1);
```

Now your script will work.

Comment: Sure , I just had to wait 10 minutes before I can set the correct answer.

Comment: @Toni note that there are several _correct_ answers but your _accepted_ answer is the one that you consider the best. The aim of the delay is to encourage participation and to provide an opportunity for you to compare your options. If this is your favourite answer, then that's fair enough but you shouldn't rush your decision.

Comment: @TomFenech I understan what u  are trying to say . This was first correct answer and its working for me, I think it will be unfair to check some other  answer if this one was first and corect, anyway I am  gratefull to everyone who tryed to help me .

Comment: @Toni I wasn't suggesting that you should accept another answer, only that you shouldn't feel rushed to make a decision in future. Don't forget that if you consider other answers helpful, you can upvote as many as you want (including this one if you haven't done so already).

Answer (score 2):

Your Date-Format is **not valid**. Check this site for the allowed formats: http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

This is why the function `strtotime()` returns `false` instead.

Answer (score 2):

No need to convert your input strings, you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) like this:

```
<?php
$date1 = "22/07/2014";
$time1 = "12:05";

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("j/m/Y H:i", "$date1 $time1");    
$now = new DateTime();

if ($dt < $now) {
    echo "time has passed";
}
?>
```

DateTime objects can be compared using `>` and `<`. If no arguments are passed to the constructor, the object takes the default value of the current date and time.

The first argument to `createFromFormat` is the format string, which allows you to specify the exact format of the date and time. See the link above for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the next format of date:

```
22-07-2014;
22.07.2014;
2014/07/22;
```

or convert it:

```
$date1 = str_replace('/','-',$_POST['date1']); // example: 22/07/2014
$time1 = $_POST['time1']; // example: 12:05

$date3 = $date1 . ' ' . $time1;
$date4 = strtotime($date3);

if(time()>$date4)...
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format is wrong. You have to change it

```
$date1 = $_POST['date1']; // example: 22/07/2014
$time1 = $_POST['time1']; // 12:05
$explodedate = explode("/",$date1);
$setdate = $explodedate[1].'/'.$explodedate[0].'/'.$explodedate[2];
$date3 = $setdate . ' ' . $time1;
$date_timestammp = strtotime($date3);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with `DateTime` class

```
$date1 = "20/07/2014"; // example: 22/07/2014
$time1 = "12:05"; // example: 12:05

$myDate = new DateTime(str_replace("/", "-",$date1) . $time1);

$now = new DateTime('now');

if($myDate > $now) // false
{
    ...
```